# AWS Code Deploy Deployment Failed "ScriptFailed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am using code deploy to deploy asp.net project deployment failed and this is the event  log 
**Event Logs**
Event details
Error code
ScriptFailed
Script name
scripts/stop_service
Message "

- Script at specified location: scripts/stop_service run as user root failed with exit code 5
- Logs : 
  LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop
- Script - scripts/stop_service
- [stderr]Failed to stop apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not loaded.
- [stderr]Failed to stop kestrel-aspnetcoreapp.service: Unit kestrel-aspnetcoreapp.service not loaded.

**Script loaded**

```
"#!/bin/bash"

"#stop apache"
"systemctl stop apache2.service"

"#stop dotnet application"
"systemctl stop kestrel-aspnetcoreapp.service"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands to stop apache2 and dotnet service in your script --

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service
sudo systemctl stop kestrel-aspnetcoreapp.service
```

Means you have to place `sudo` before your commands